# How do I find the magnitude and direction of the magnetic field of a permanent magnet at an arbitrary point using physics equations?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I've been wanting to do some simulations on my computer that illustrate the magnetic field of a magnet. I have quite a few .5/.5/.5" cubic neodymium magnets and have been arranging them together to form odd shapes that result in odd fields. I want a graphical representation of these fields, not just me holding a magnet in the palm of my hand and waving it over the magnets (not very scientific!).

Correct me if I am wrong, but I do know that to calculate the B-field at an arbitrary point relative to a magnet that you use the Biot-Savart law, which is [clearly spelled out on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law).

Unfortunately I do not have the academic background to make sense of this beautiful little equation. What I want is to pick a number of arbitrary points in relation to one or more magnets (in this case bar magnets will suffice since that is what I have), say one point every 0.05 inches cubed, and then plot the B-field force vectors at those points. It will thus illustrate the B-field vectors as lines with whose direction and length correspond to the direction and magnitude of the B-field vectors respectively.

How would I go about plotting these B-field vectors?

Comment: The Biot-Savart law tells you the magnetic field produced by an electric current, not the field of a permanent magnet.

Comment: I'll rename, but what equations should I be using?

Comment: Calculating the field near a finite-sized permanent magnet is hard. You can read about it here: http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/rmfe/v59n1/v59n1a2.pdf. If you want to treat a magnet as a point, you can consider it as a magnetic dipole field, which *does* have a simple formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole

Comment: Nitpick: doing a crude experiment to gain an intuition about the system you’re looking at is *extremely* scientific. It’s not particularly *precise*, but all science is rooted in observation and your observations have yielded a lot of information. You know, for example, that the length scale over which your fields drop off is on the order of centimeters, not millimeters or meters. And while you don’t have much hard data, you have a fairly good idea of what the (very complex) field actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a while but I have been interested in performing a similar experiment and I came across this website. I hope this helps:
https://www.magnet-sdm.com/2017/08/01/magnetic-field-strength-permanent-magnet/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/365806)

Comment: The reference gives the field only on the axis of symmetry, and the constant, $B_r$, is not clearly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the magnetic field in the vicinity of a configuration of magnets would be an extremely challenging project. You can replace each magnet by a current carrying solenoid of the same size, shape, and dipole moment. You then use the Biot-Savart formula as the basis for a computerized numeric integration of the contributions from each short segment of current carrying wire, at each point of interest in the field.